# labeling an image with piece of a puzzle

Tags: matlab

I have a picture on which are the different pieces of a puzzle. i would like to write a program with matlab that allows me to get the different pieces of the puzzle each on a picture. so far i just manage to get the different pieces in binary picture and not in color picture. does anyone have an idea?

My code:

````
close all;
clc
A = imread('pieces.jpg');
figure, imshow(A);
title('Original Image');
level = graythresh(A);
%D = im2gray(A);
B = ~im2bw(A, 0.672);
figure, imshow(B);
C = imfill(B, 'holes');
figure, imshow(C);
label = bwlabel(C);
max(max(label))
for j = 1:max(max(label))
[row,col] = find(label==j);
len=max(row)-min(row)+2;
breadth=max(col)-min(col)+2;
target=uint8(zeros([len breadth]));
sy = min(col)-1;
sx = min(row)-1;
for i=1:size(row,1)
x=row(i,1) - sx;
y=col(i,1) - sy;
target(x,y) = A(row(i,1),col(i,1));
end
figure,imshow(target);
end```
````

Comment: Not quite on topic, but an interesting question. Please post the picture.